# A question on SUSY transformation

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, supersymmetry, representation-theory

I am learning the SUSY. At present, I am not clear for one point about the SUSY transformation:
$$\delta_{\epsilon} \phi= \sqrt{2}\epsilon\psi$$
(I write here  just for bosonic part, for e.g)

My question is: why is the commutator of two SUSY transformations, $\delta_{\epsilon_1}\delta_{\epsilon_2} - \delta_{\epsilon_2}\delta_{\epsilon_1}$, must be a symmetry transformation, in particular, the translational transformation, in this case?

Comment: because $\delta_\epsilon A\equiv i\epsilon[Q,A]$ and $\{Q,Q^\dagger\}\equiv P^\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

1. In general it is assumed that symmetry transformations form a representation a group $G$ (which is called the symmetry group). In case of a Lie group $G$, at the infinitesimal level, the symmetry transformations form a representation of the corresponding Lie algebra. In particular, the commutator of two infinitesimal symmetry transformations is again a symmetry transformation.
2. Concerning OP's last question: It is a hallmark of SUSY transformations that their commutator is spacetime translations. Or in terms of generators: The commutator of SUSY charges is proportional to energy/momentum.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a problem left, I understand that the commutator of two inf. symmetry transformation is again a symmetry transformation, but why it might be the Lorentz transformations, for e.g, not another SUSY transformation itself?

Comment: For starters, it has to respect Grassmann-parity, so e.g. the commutator of two Grassmann-odd SUSY charges must be Grassmann-even, and so forth. Moreover index structure has to match.